# how to pass a prop and call a component based on the prop name

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a card component where I want to pass an icon name to it via props.

The icons are from the react icons library.

To display normally you would do something like this:

```
import { MdCardGiftcard } from "react-icons/md";

<MdCardGiftcard />
```

But I want that component to be based on the props sent to it. Is this possible?

```
const AdminCard = ({icon}) => {
// prop 'icon' with value 'MdCardGiftcard' sent to this component
  {icon}
}
```

This is what is coming from props:

```
      <AdminCard
        title="Some title"
        endpoint="someEndpoint"
        color="blue"
        icon="MdCardGiftcard"
      />
```

Comment: You can pass ```<MdCardGiftcard />``` as a prop to ```AdminCard```

Comment: Ah! Didn't know I could do that :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
        <
```

and on admin card component

```
      const AdminCard = ({prop}) => {
     
          `<${prop.icon}/>`
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import { MdCardGiftcard } from "react-icons/md";

<AdminCard
    title="Some title"
    endpoint="someEndpoint"
    color="blue"
    icon=MdCardGiftcard
  />

const AdminCard = ({icon}) => {
    const Icon = icon; // The capitalization is important here 
    return <Icon/>;
}
```

More info about the capitalization [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't appear to display the icon though. Michael's answer seemed to be the easiest way to achieve what I wanted.